# Gradle: How to declare java version in 'java-platform' plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm using `java-platform` plugin to declare versions of dependencies, that is working fine now.

I want to also declare other things like java and kotlin languageVersion, resolutionStrategy, repositories and custom functions maybe.

I hope at least java things can be centralized there since it's called platform.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Platform plugin is not designed for specifying a JVM language versions. As specified in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html):

> A platform is a special kind of software component which doesn’t contain any sources: **it is only used to reference other libraries**, so that they play well together during dependency resolution.

To control or manage other things such as the Java language version using [toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html) or resolution strategy, your option is to [create custom Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html). The plugin can also import/use your custom Java platform as well.

Comment: My goal is to have single module defining build dependencies and parameters (like i said above). So maybe using classic module with version catalog and custom plugin is better way to go?

Comment: btw. can I put buildSrc to platform project?